# How migration on AndroidX

Tags: android, flutter, android-support-library, androidx

After migration to AndroidX, I've got the following errors:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:27.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/home/cran/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/androidx/legacy/legacy-support-core-utils/27.0.1/legacy-support-core-utils-27.0.1.pom
Required by:
         project :app > project :advanced_share

Could not find androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:27.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
Required by:
         project :app > project :image_cropper > com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.3 > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.1
         project :app > project :image_cropper > com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.3 > com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
         project :app > project :flutter_share_me > com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.42.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.42.0
         project :app > project :flutrans > com.midtrans:uikit:1.22.2 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
         project :app > project :image_cropper > com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.3 > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.1 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0
         project :app > project :image_cropper > com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.3 > com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

The library `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:27.0.1` **doesn't** exist.

You can check the [migration artifact mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#artifact_mappings):

```
com.android.support:support-core-utils -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
```

Use:

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
```